# Fetch batching while querying depends on unrelated entity

Tags: ios, core-data

Let's assume following `coredata` entities:

**User**
- userId

**Message**
 - date
 - fromId
 - toId
 - isRead
 - date

---

**App needs to:** 
 - load users who have no messages with current user 
 - load users who have messages with current user and sort them by the `date` of last message
 - count total unread messages to current user

**Current logic:**
- fetch all users 
- fetch all messages for each user
- sort users based on messages

This is done in a background context, but still the delay is considerable when 500+ users needs to be displayed.

I'd like to make it faster, usually batching is the way to go. What's my best bet in implementing `NSFetchedResultsController` / `batching`? I'd like to stay away from data model changes (e.g. setting `Message` as relation of `User`) and data migrations.

Comment: Have you done any reading or other research on batching and faulting? Is it worth providing an example of your code to better explain the problem to others?

Comment: @andrewbuilder Sure. Normally, I'd set `batch size` on `fetch request` and use `fetched results controller`. In this case I can't seem to have a way to use `messages` in predicate for `User`.

Comment: @andrewbuilder please check out `Current logic:` I've added to better explain what's going on.

Comment: Why the fear of model changes?  is the app already published on the app store?

Comment: @JonRose yes, we'd prefer to stay away from data migrations for now.